# How do i extract the highest value and print out the highest value key? Using for or while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using a for or while loop, how can I extract the highest value and print out the highest value key?

```
data = {
    'Jeremy':73284, 
    'Hansel':8784.3, 
    'Uee':9480938.2, 
    'Seolhyun':984958.3, 
    'Ketsuno Ana':24131, 
    'Trump':45789
}
```

Comment: You could just use the `max` built in function. `max(data) -> 'Uee'`

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? NB : you insist on the fact you have to use a while or for loop so it's obviously homework. Asking for help on homework is ok, but you have to show some effort.

Comment: Hi marko i under max function does the trick but i need to use for or while loop for this

Comment: I agree with @bruno, this shouldn't be too hard of a solution. Showing some effort would go a long way on this site.

Comment: Mark bruno I actually read some of the code on this site however i couldnt understand them as some of them are 2.7 and i still quite new at this. I am able to get the highest value but i not sure how to get the highest value key hence i am at this site asking for help. I am more of trying to understand the logic and concept of the this than completing this homework.

Comment: @h3ll, I tried to add some explanations according to your last comment. The concept is not that hard to absorb.

Comment: Thanks alot @MagedSaeed! Yes your coding is simple and understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the max by looping through the keys saving the key of the highest value while going through the dictionary. Finally, print the key with its corresponding value.

Something like this shall work. It is with a `for` loop in `python3`.

```
data = { 'Jeremy':73284, 'Hansel':8784.3, 'Uee':9480938.2, 'Seolhyun':984958.3, 'Ketsuno Ana':24131, 'Trump':45789 }
maximum = 'Jeremy'
for key in data.keys():
    if data[key] > data[maximum]:
        maximum = key
print('Maximum:'+maximum+", the value is:"+str(data[maximum]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1. using for or while loop (as asked)

```
>>> data = {'Jeremy': 73284, 'Hansel': 8784.3, 'Uee': 9480938.2, 'Seolhyun': 984958.3, 'Ketsuno Ana': 24131, 'Trump': 45789}
>>> 
>>> max_k = None
>>> max_v = None
>>> for k, v in data.items():
...     if max_v is None or v > max_v:
...         max_v = v
...         max_k = k
... 
>>> print(max_k)
Uee
```

## 2. using [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

**Python 2**

```
>>> import operator
>>> data = {'Jeremy':73284, 'Hansel':8784.3, 'Uee':9480938.2, 'Seolhyun':984958.3, 'Ketsuno Ana':24131, 'Trump':45789}
>>> max(data.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
'Uee'
```

**Python 3**

```
>>> import operator
>>> data = {'Jeremy':73284, 'Hansel':8784.3, 'Uee':9480938.2, 'Seolhyun':984958.3, 'Ketsuno Ana':24131, 'Trump':45789}
>>> max(data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
'Uee'
```

**EDIT**

## using max() easier

```
>>> data = {'Jeremy': 73284, 'Hansel': 8784.3, 'Uee': 9480938.2, 'Seolhyun': 984958.3, 'Ketsuno Ana': 24131, 'Trump': 45789}
>>> max(data)
'Uee'
```